# Given k sorted numbers, what is the minimum cost to turn them into consecutive numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, contiguous

Suppose, we are given a sorted list of *k* numbers. Now, we want to convert this sorted list into a list having consecutive numbers. The only operation allowed is that we can increase/decrease a number by one. Performing every such operation will result in increasing the total cost by one.

Now, how to minimize the total cost while converting the list as mentioned?

One idea that I have is to get the median of the sorted list and arrange the numbers around the median. After that just add the absolute difference between the corresponding numbers in the newly created list and the original list. But, this is just an intuitive method. I don't have any proof of it.

P.S.:

```
Here's an example-
Sorted list: -96, -75, -53, -24.
We can convert this list into a consecutive list by various methods. 
The optimal one is: -58, -59, -60, -61
Cost: 90
```

This is a sub-part of a [problem from Topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13625).

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: How fast does it need to be?

Comment: my guess the downvote since this smells a lot of like a homework/school work question

Comment: Well, this is not a homework for sure. It's a subpart of a problem from Topcoder: http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=13625

Comment: @IVlad The maximum number of elements in the list can be 50. Now, this needs to run under one second. But, the range of numbers in the list can be pretty huge (~10^7). So, one can't simply iterate in the range and check for every integer in the range.

Comment: If you know the median, you can compute any of the involved numbers in that sequence based on its position, so you don't even need a sequence any more.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Didn't get your comment. What do you mean by, "you don't need a sequence any more"?

Comment: If the requirements for the resulting data structure boil down to "give me the N-th number in constant time", computing it on demand based on position, size and median is a solution that doesn't even require any storage for the individual elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

1. Let's assume that these numbers are `x, x + 1, x + n - 1`. Then the cost is `sum i = 0 ... n - 1 of abs(a[i] - (x + i))`. Let's call it `f(x)`.
2. `f(x)` is piece-wise linear and it approaches infinity as `x` approaches `+infinity` or `-infinity`. It means that its minimum is reached in one of the end points.
3. The end points are `a[0], a[1] - 1, a[2] - 2, ..., a[n - 1] - (n - 1)`. So we can just try all of them and pick the best.

Comment: Can you please explain, how did you reach at the conclusion - "its minimum is reached in one of the end points."?

Comment: @Sankalp Let's assume that we stand in some point `x`. Let's start moving to the left and to the right from it. It is decreasing(non-strictly) in at least one direction. It cannot be the one that leads to infinity(or -infinity). Thus, we will hit some end point that has a value at least as small as in `x`.

Comment: So, if I get you correctly, what you are trying to say is that `f(x)` will decrease in at least one direction and after some point will reach its minimum value, right?

Comment: @Sankalp Not necessary global minimum. Just an end point of this particular segment with a value smaller or equal to `f(x)`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I am confused so much, just bear with me a bit. I am still not able to digest the argument. I am trying to understand the proof by plotting a graph. Suppose, we have only one element in the list, then minimum for |a[0] - x| would be when a[0] = x. Now, to calculate minimum for |a[0] - x| + |a[1] - (x+1)|, we either need to set a[0] = x or a[1] = (x + 1). Am I correct?

Comment: @Sankalp Yes, exactly.

Comment: Finally got the idea. The function will always keep on decreasing until we hit a point (i.e. a[0] or a[1], etc.). Thanks for being patient!

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that the solution is in increasing order and `m`, `M` are the minimum and maximum value of the sorted list. The other case will be handled the same way.

Each solution is defined by the number assigned to the first element. If this number is very small then increasing it by one will reduce the cost. We can continue increasing this number until the cost grows. From this point the cost will continuously grow. So the optimum will be a local minimum and we can find it by using binary search. The range we are going to search will be `[m - n, M + n]` where `n` is the number of elements:

```
l = [-96, -75, -53, -24]

# Cost if initial value is x
def cost(l, x):
    return sum(abs(i - v) for i, v in enumerate(l, x))

def find(l):
    a, b = l[0] - len(l), l[-1] + len(l)
    while a < b:
        m = (a + b) / 2
        if cost(l, m + 1) >= cost(l, m) <= cost(l, m - 1): # Local minimum
            return m
        if cost(l, m + 1) < cost(l, m):
            a = m + 1
        else:
            b = m - 1
    return b
```

Testing:

```
>>> initial = find(l)
>>> range(initial, initial + len(l))
[-60, -59, -58, -57]
>>> cost(l, initial)
90
```

Comment: Nice idea. Binary search is amazing!